# cocos2d-android CCLabel is blinking while using it as countdown timer

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am using CClabel.setString() for showing countdown timer in my game application, but while updating time it blinks and then update the time. My code is :

```
timerLabel = CCLabel.makeLabel("0.00", "courier", (float) 15);
timerLabel.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(330,300));
timerLabel.setColor(ccColor3B.ccBLUE);
addChild(timerLabel,4);

------------------
timerLabel.setString(total_time+".00");
```

can anyone help please.
Thanking You
Santanu